# Binding Refresh on a dataGrid WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, entity-framework-mapping

Hey guys I have problem with binding and refreshing binding.

I am using Entity Framework with WindowsForms...

I am retrieving orders from Shipping Queue and binding them to the grid.

if I open another form and and move Order X to different Queue, my grid does not reflect that...

So for example, the Main form has a two grids and a button

```
Grid 1 = Orders in Shipping Queue 
Grid 2 = Orders in New Order Queue
Button 1 = Manage Orders
```

If I click my "Manage Orders" button and open up Order X that is in the Shipping Queue and move it to the New Orders Queue, I want the change to be reflected in the grids.

I tried different stuff and the cheapest and best solution I came up with was to call update on the grids every few minutes but I feel that there must be a better way...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the values you're binding to are calling OnPropertyChanged() properly.

```
public class Class1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int myValue;
    public int MyValue
    {
        get { return myValue; }
        set 
        {
            if (myValue != value)
            {
                myValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        var notify = PropertyChanged;
        if (notify != null)
            notify(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that and see how it will go